# Why can't I open this file for reading in python?

Tags: python

I'm working in Python and I'm confused why I can't open the file I'm trying to. The code is pretty simple. Here it is.

```
import os
def main():
  FILE_NAME = "default_template.csv"
  source_path = os.path.join("Documents", FILE_NAME)
  file = open(source_path, "r")
```

At this point I get

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Documents/FILE_NAME'.
```

I also decided to try to change directories for whatever reason using `os.chdir()` and passing just about every high level directory on my computer in seperately and nothing worked. In an attempt to find the fix for opening a file I tried editing the path in a bunch of different ways.

I've tried something like:

```
os.path.join("/derek/Documents", FILE_NAME)

os.path.join("/Documents", FILE_NAME)

os.path.join("~/derek/Documents", FILE_NAME)

os.path.join("~", FILE_NAME)
```

If anyone could help me out I would be extremely thankful. I'm still new to using python to navigate and manage files.

Comment: Those are virtual folders, the real ones are hidden from you by the OS, I'm afraid. That said, you didn't get "No such file or directory: 'Documents/FILE_NAME'", unless you somewhere had such a string.

Comment: would be useful to actually show the full path of the file...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: use `/home/derek/<file_name>`. This should work. Or you can also add path relative to `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't expand ~ by default. To make it work try [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.

```
source_path = os.path.join("~/Documents", FILE_NAME)
source_path = os.path.expanduser(source_path)
```